# UItableView not populating while offline? swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, nsuserdefaults

The problem is really, that while offline the UItableview is not populating. Basically while online it will read from a php coded website in json and parse its data to NSUserdefaults and It will display data using the defaults set. This works very well when online.

I tested it like this. first I run the code while online( wifi connected ) to first populate the defaults, then exit the tableview, turn wifi off, and then go back in. Nothing shows. I put a breakpoint/print text where the code should had run, but it breakpoint never got excuted, the print text never got printed.

is there a reason why the code isnt running when offline? am i missing a setting i should add?

```
var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()
    var dateArray:[String] = [String]()

    class Singleton {
        static let sharedInstance: UserDefaults = {
            let instance = UserDefaults.standard
            // setup code
            return instance
        }()
    }
    //let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaults = Singleton.sharedInstance


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //removeDefaults()
        if (isInternetAvailable() == true)
            {
            self.retrieveMessages("")
            //storeLocal()
            }
        else {
            // TODO data is available but not displayed ??

            for (key, value) in defaults.dictionaryRepresentation() {
                print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
            }
        }

        //display current notification


        //nRead()
        self.notificationTable.dataSource = self
        self.notificationTable.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }


        func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

            return messagesArray.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            // this code does not run when offline 
            //test
            let nCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nCell") as UITableViewCell!

            //let myLabelTitle = nCell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            let myLabelDate = nCell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
            let myLabelDescription = nCell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
            //messagesArray ["nContent":["Test1", "Test2"]]

            myLabelDescription.text = defaults.string(forKey: "nDescription\(indexPath.row + 1)")
            myLabelDate.text = defaults.string(forKey: "nDate\(indexPath.row + 1)")
            //print(defaults.string(forKey:"nDate1"))
            print("this code runs even while offline")


            let readValue = defaults.string(forKey: "nRead\(indexPath.row + 1)")

            if (readValue == "1" )
                {
                    myLabelDate.textColor = UIColor.black
                }
            else
                {
                    myLabelDate.textColor = UIColor.red
                }

            return nCell!

        }
```

Comment: You need to show us the code relevant for populating `NSUserDefaults` from network responses and also fetching the data from it while being offline. How do you detect being offline in the 1st place?

Comment: Did you check in which block of if else statement is your code going into when you are testing offline? I mean, how are you checking Internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

            return messagesArray.count
        }
```

messagesArray.count prints 0, thus the code isn't running. fixed my own issue